# How to use find().each() while excluding a specific classname

Tags: jquery

I currently have script that exports HTML Table to a CSV file.

It's working and exporting the table as expected but it exports everything..
I wanted to exclude the row that has the `.hidden` class in it.

I tried using the `:not()` selector and the `.not()` method in the `.find("tr")` part but neither of it seems to be working.

Here's the part of the code that loops through the `<tr>`: ( The whole script is from this js plugin called [Table2Download](https://github.com/aurelianzaha/table2download/blob/master/js/table2download.js) )

```
$(this).find("tr:not(.hidden)").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find("td").length > 0) {
        var sep = "";
        $(this).find("td").each(function () {
            csv += sep + settings.quotes + $(this).text() + settings.quotes;
            sep = settings.separator;
        });
        csv += settings.newline;                
    } else if ($(this).find("th").length > 0) {
        var sep = "";
        $(this).find("th").each(function () {
            csv += sep + settings.quotes + $(this).text() + settings.quotes;
            sep = settings.separator;
        });
        csv += settings.newline;                
   }
 }
```

Here's a sample HTML table:

```
<table class="test-table">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th> Name </th>
      <th> Test </th>
      <th> Date </th>
      <th> Score </th>
      <th> something else </th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="hidden">
       <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
       <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
       <td title="Date">03/08/2017</td>
       <td title="Score">4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
       <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
       <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
       <td title="Date">03/08/2017</td>
       <td title="Score">5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="odd">
       <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
       <td title="Test">exam 2</td>
       <td title="Date">03/08/2017</td>
       <td title="Score">7</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
        <td title="Name">Wendy Doe</td>
        <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
        <td title="Date">03/08/2017</td>
        <td title="Score">7</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="hidden">
        <td title="Name">Wendy Doe</td>
        <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
        <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
        <td title="Score">4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="hidden">
        <td title="Name">Wendy Doe</td>
        <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
        <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
        <td title="Score">3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you add html mark up

Comment: What is `this` in `$(this).find("tr:not(.hidden)")`?

Comment: @Satpal It's the table class

Comment: should it be just `$("tr:not(.hidden)")`

Comment: @guradio tried, not working either.

Comment: Have you tried to just simply `console.log` the results and check if they're the rows you're looking for?

Comment: @A.Lau I think it's because of how the order of the scripts are running,  is there a way where I can run the exporter function only when the download button is clicked not when the page loads?

Comment: yes... put the download part into a function, then add an `onclick` to the button which takes the function

Comment: @A.Lau Happy to say I worked this one out, I just used another script for the csv exporter and made some changes! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("tr:not(.hidden)").each(function() {
  $(this).find("td").css("color", "red")




})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="test-table">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th> Name </th>
      <th> Test </th>
      <th> Date </th>
      <th> Score </th>
      <th> something else </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="hidden">
      <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
      <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
      <td title="Date">03/08/2017</td>
      <td title="Score">4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
      <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
      <td title="Date">03/08/2017</td>
      <td title="Score">5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="odd">
      <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
      <td title="Test">exam 2</td>
      <td title="Date">03/08/2017</td>
      <td title="Score">7</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
      <td title="Name">Wendy Doe</td>
      <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
      <td title="Date">03/08/2017</td>
      <td title="Score">7</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="hidden">
      <td title="Name">Wendy Doe</td>
      <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
      <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
      <td title="Score">4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="hidden">
      <td title="Name">Wendy Doe</td>
      <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
      <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
      <td title="Score">3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Use only `$("tr:not(.hidden)")`

Comment: i tried removing the find() part and it stil is not working for me >.<

Comment: I only have one table on that whole page

Comment: no errors either, could it be possible that hidden class is added via another script that's causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working fine for me. I put `.test-table` instead of `this`. But removing the `.find()` altogether and just targeting the tr works too as in guradio's answer.

```js
var csv = '';
var settings = {quotes:'"',separator:',',newline:"\n"}
$(".test-table").find("tr:not(.hidden)").each(function () {
    if ($(this).find("td").length > 0) {
        var sep = "";
        $(this).find("td").each(function () {
            csv += sep + settings.quotes + $(this).text() + settings.quotes;
            sep = settings.separator;
        });
        csv += settings.newline;                
    } else if ($(this).find("th").length > 0) {
        var sep = "";
        $(this).find("th").each(function () {
            csv += sep + settings.quotes + $(this).text() + settings.quotes;
            sep = settings.separator;
        });
        csv += settings.newline;                
   }
 });
 console.log(csv);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="test-table">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th> Name </th>
      <th> Test </th>
      <th> Date </th>
      <th> Score </th>
      <th> something else </th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="hidden">
       <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
       <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
       <td title="Date">03/08/2017</td>
       <td title="Score">4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
       <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
       <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
       <td title="Date">03/08/2017</td>
       <td title="Score">5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="odd">
       <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
       <td title="Test">exam 2</td>
       <td title="Date">03/08/2017</td>
       <td title="Score">7</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
        <td title="Name">Wendy Doe</td>
        <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
        <td title="Date">03/08/2017</td>
        <td title="Score">7</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="hidden">
        <td title="Name">Wendy Doe</td>
        <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
        <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
        <td title="Score">4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="hidden">
        <td title="Name">Wendy Doe</td>
        <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
        <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
        <td title="Score">3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it maybe because my site is running from wordpress?

Comment: @M.Y That shouldn't matter. Are you sure the rows you want to skip have the right class (hidden)?

Comment: yes, actually my table has a filter that only adds a hidden class to the rows that needs to be filtered out. so if the filter is on `hidden` class is added to some rows.

Comment: @M.Y Maybe there is something wrong with that filter. Also, you are running this code AFTER you turn on the filter right? Otherwise, it won't see those classes.

Comment: oh, maybe that's it. I'm running this script as the page loads. But if that's what's causing the problem is there a way where I can export everything when the filter is off and also export the filtered table too?

Comment: So you should just copy this code to a point in the filtering code after the classes are added.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that one out! I'll try and see if I make it work :D I'm a beginner in javascript so still learning >.<

Answer (score 0):

WordPress comes pre-packaged with a copy of jQuery.

When WordPress’ jQuery is loaded, it uses [compatibility mode](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/), which is a mechanism for avoiding conflicts with other language libraries.

So you can’t use the dollar sign **`$`** directly as you would in other projects. When writing jQuery for WordPress you need to use **`jQuery`** instead. Check out example below:

```js
var $hiddenTr = jQuery("tr").not(".hidden");

$hiddenTr.each(function() {
    jQuery(this).find("td").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="test-table">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th> Name </th>
      <th> Test </th>
      <th> Date </th>
      <th> Score </th>
      <th> something else </th>
  </tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="hidden">
       <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
       <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
       <td title="Date">03/08/2017</td>
       <td title="Score">4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
       <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
       <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
       <td title="Date">03/08/2017</td>
       <td title="Score">5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="odd">
       <td title="Name">John Doe</td>
       <td title="Test">exam 2</td>
       <td title="Date">03/08/2017</td>
       <td title="Score">7</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="even">
        <td title="Name">Wendy Doe</td>
        <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
        <td title="Date">03/08/2017</td>
        <td title="Score">7</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="hidden">
        <td title="Name">Wendy Doe</td>
        <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
        <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
        <td title="Score">4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="hidden">
        <td title="Name">Wendy Doe</td>
        <td title="Test">exam 1</td>
        <td title="Date">02/11/2017</td>
        <td title="Score">3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who posted!!
I made a work around for this one by using another script!

I think the problem with the code before was the exporting link runs and creates the file before my other javascript code so it's not reading the `.hidden` class which is only added via javascript (with checkbox `onchange` event).

Anyways, with this new code I change it a little bit to exclude the `.hidden` class with this line.

```
var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td),tr:has(th)').not('tr.hidden')
```